# Remove Jest error "consider using the jsdom test environment"

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs, jsdom

the context is the following: I am learning unit testing using Jest. My current enviroment is Jest with Webpack as I am using ES6 Modules. In my current project, I'm only testing JavaScript logic, not the UI. Ideally, Jest would skip over my imported files and only test functions in my current file. The test suite was working as expected, until I imported a DOM rendering file into my main JS file (import './display.js'). I see this error in every test I run.

```
import './display.js';
import './style.css';
import {pubSub, ps} from './subscriptions.js';
import {Gameboard, tiles} from './gameboard.js'
```

If I don't add import './display.js', I get this error:
Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

I did try installing jsdom as well, but nothing happens.
I also tried adding './display.js' to an excluded files list in my package.json, but that didn't work either.
I used:
collectCoverageFrom: ['!src/display.js']

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "battleship",
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "!src/display.js"
    ]
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "jest --watch *.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/itsaflamingo/Battleship.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/itsaflamingo/Battleship/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/itsaflamingo/Battleship#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.6",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "^8.7.1",
    "acorn-import-assertions": "^1.8.0",
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.5.2",
    "ansi-regex": "^5.0.1",
    "boolbase": "^1.0.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.21.1",
    "buffer-from": "^1.1.2",
    "camel-case": "^4.1.2",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001361",
    "chrome-trace-event": "^1.0.3",
    "clean-css": "^5.3.0",
    "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
    "colorette": "^2.0.19",
    "commander": "^2.20.3",
    "cross-spawn": "^7.0.3",
    "css-select": "^4.3.0",
    "css-what": "^6.1.0",
    "cssesc": "^3.0.0",
    "dom-converter": "^0.2.0",
    "dom-serializer": "^1.4.1",
    "domelementtype": "^2.3.0",
    "domhandler": "^4.3.1",
    "domutils": "^2.8.0",
    "dot-case": "^3.0.4",
    "electron-to-chromium": "^1.4.173",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^5.10.0",
    "entities": "^2.2.0",
    "envinfo": "^7.8.1",
    "es-module-lexer": "^0.9.3",
    "escalade": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-scope": "^5.1.1",
    "esrecurse": "^4.3.0",
    "estraverse": "^4.3.0",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^3.1.3",
    "fast-json-stable-stringify": "^2.1.0",
    "fastest-levenshtein": "^1.0.12",
    "find-up": "^4.1.0",
    "function-bind": "^1.1.1",
    "glob-to-regexp": "^0.4.1",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.2.10",
    "has": "^1.0.3",
    "has-flag": "^4.0.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "html-minifier-terser": "^6.1.0",
    "htmlparser2": "^6.1.0",
    "icss-utils": "^5.1.0",
    "import-local": "^3.1.0",
    "interpret": "^2.2.0",
    "is-core-module": "^2.9.0",
    "is-plain-object": "^2.0.4",
    "isexe": "^2.0.0",
    "isobject": "^3.0.1",
    "jest-worker": "^27.5.1",
    "jsdom": "^20.0.0",
    "json-parse-even-better-errors": "^2.3.1",
    "json-schema-traverse": "^0.4.1",
    "kind-of": "^6.0.3",
    "loader-runner": "^4.3.0",
    "locate-path": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lower-case": "^2.0.2",
    "lru-cache": "^6.0.0",
    "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "mime-db": "^1.52.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "nanoid": "^3.3.4",
    "neo-async": "^2.6.2",
    "no-case": "^3.0.4",
    "node-releases": "^2.0.5",
    "nth-check": "^2.1.1",
    "p-limit": "^2.3.0",
    "p-locate": "^4.1.0",
    "p-try": "^2.2.0",
    "param-case": "^3.0.4",
    "pascal-case": "^3.1.2",
    "path-exists": "^4.0.0",
    "path-key": "^3.1.1",
    "path-parse": "^1.0.7",
    "picocolors": "^1.0.0",
    "pkg-dir": "^4.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-modules-extract-imports": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-modules-local-by-default": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-modules-scope": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-modules-values": "^4.0.0",
    "postcss-selector-parser": "^6.0.10",
    "postcss-value-parser": "^4.2.0",
    "pretty-error": "^4.0.0",
    "punycode": "^2.1.1",
    "randombytes": "^2.1.0",
    "rechoir": "^0.7.1",
    "relateurl": "^0.2.7",
    "renderkid": "^3.0.0",
    "resolve": "^1.22.1",
    "resolve-cwd": "^3.0.0",
    "resolve-from": "^5.0.0",
    "safe-buffer": "^5.2.1",
    "schema-utils": "^3.1.1",
    "semver": "^7.3.7",
    "serialize-javascript": "^6.0.0",
    "shallow-clone": "^3.0.1",
    "shebang-command": "^2.0.0",
    "shebang-regex": "^3.0.0",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1",
    "source-map-js": "^1.0.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.21",
    "strip-ansi": "^6.0.1",
    "supports-color": "^8.1.1",
    "supports-preserve-symlinks-flag": "^1.0.0",
    "tapable": "^2.2.1",
    "terser": "^5.14.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.3",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "update-browserslist-db": "^1.0.4",
    "uri-js": "^4.4.1",
    "util-deprecate": "^1.0.2",
    "utila": "^0.4.0",
    "watchpack": "^2.4.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
    "webpack-sources": "^3.2.3",
    "which": "^2.0.2",
    "wildcard": "^2.0.0",
    "yallist": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": []
}
```

This is my webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
      index: './src/index.js',
      print: './src/print.js',
      display: './src/display.js',
      subscriptions: './src/subscriptions.js'
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'Battleship',
      }),
    ],
     output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
       clean: true,
     },
     module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          },
        ],
      },
   };
```

This is the test I am running for index.js:

```
import {Ship, Players, playerBoats} from './index';

test('factory function returns object', () => {
    expect(Ship('Carrier', 5)).toMatchObject({
        boatName: 'Carrier',
        length: 5,
        hitSpot: [],
        sunk: false,
    });
})

test('when hit, factory function returns modified object', () => {
    expect(Ship('Destroyer', 2).isHit(1, playerBoats)).toMatchObject({
        boatName: 'Destroyer',
        coordinates: [],
        length: 2,
        hitSpot: [1],
        sunk: false,
    });
})

test('player can attack computer multiple times', () => {
    expect(Players().Player().playerAttack(4)).toMatchObject({
        boatName: 'Carrier',
        coordinates: [2, 3, 4],
        length: 5,
        hitSpot: [2, 4],
        sunk: false,
    })
})
```

I am running Linux on Chromebook and using VS Code, I'm not sure if that makes a difference. I just want to be able to skip UI tests with Jest.

Comment: What about your Jest config file? Are you specifying `jsdom` as the `testEnvironment`?

Comment: It throws error " Test environment jest-environment-jsdom cannot be found."

Comment: You said in your post that you tried to install `jest-environment-jsdom`. Have you `npm i -D jest-environment-jsdom` ?

Comment: I'm still receiving the error. I kind of solved it by creating a new folder and copy-pasting all my code into it, and re-installing all dependencies in this new folder. 

I now don't have to import my display.js into index.js for the contents to render, so the test suite doesn't have access to the DOM methods which were causing it to throw errors. It's not perfect as I am still getting errors whenever a script file has access to the DOM, but I can just separate DOM and javascript and hopefully that will be a solution. 
Thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Came back to answer as I struggled with this for a while. My issue was that I was not separating my UI and logic, and jest does not accept DOM methods or selectors unless specified.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).